Why is this a potential memory leak?
typedef struct _MY_STRUCTURE_ {
    int param1;
    int param2;
    int param3;
    int param4;
    int param5;
    int param6;
} MY_STRUCTURE, *pMY_STRUCTURE;

class Test {
    public:
    void doSomethings(pMY_STRUCTURE myStructure);
};

void Test::doSomethings(pMY_STRUCTURE myStructure) {
    printf("%p\n", &myStructure->param2);
    myStructure->param1 = 10;
}

int main() {
    pMY_STRUCTURE myStructure = (pMY_STRUCTURE)malloc( sizeof(pMY_STRUCTURE) );
    Test *t = new Test();
    
    myStructure->param2 = 0;
    // Prints 0
    printf("%i\n", myStructure->param2);

    // Prints the address
    printf("%p\n", &myStructure->param2);
    t->doSomethings(myStructure);

    // Warning about potential memory leak?
    printf("%p\n", &myStructure->param2);
}

As displayed in my code documentation, the line that makes the last printf statement has a potential memory leak, according to Qt software. Why is this potentially a memory leak? Is this the case, and if so then why?
The message:

Potential leak of memory pointed to by 't' [clang-analyzer-cplusplus.NewDeleteLeaks]

In addition, this code is executing just fine, but I have another piece of code in the same style but more functionalities and I find that the printf statement in the void is providing a different address compared to the printf statements before and after the void call.

Where do you delete t?

Each new must be paired with delete. The analyzer is showing that you don't do that.

There are calls to malloc and new in the code but no matching free or delete. Those are memory leaks. The malloc call is incorrect. You are allocating space for a pointer sizeof(pMY_STRUCTURE) and treating that as if you allocated space for a structure sizeof(MY_STRUCTURE).

Thanks @RetiredNinja, From that I can take that I should've done the latter, sizeof(MY_STRUCTURE) rather than sizeof(pMY_STRUCTURE) ?

Executing just fine? Let's see.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Thank you, this helps me visualize things! Could you maybe elaborate (explain) a bit more on what is happening and why my example code causes this overflow? Trying to learn from this :)

Side note: names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (_MY_STRUCTURE_) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Also, you don't need to do that typedef struct ... MY_STRUCTURE dance in C++. struct MY_STRUCTURE ... works just fine. And pMY_STRUCTURE is just a bad idea all around.

Not a potential leak; this is 2 certain memory leaks. Why does a novice jump onto pointers? Pointers - specially raw pointers - are expert stuff.

In C++ unlearn to use new delete,  and really really forget malloc ever existed. Your Test is not polymorphic at all so no need to new it.  In C++ when you need to allocate memory use std::make_unique or std::make_shared or use containers like std::vector.  You use prinft (which is "C") and even your struct is declared in a "C" style not "C++", so the best advice I can give you right now, is stop what you are doing and get a better source to learn C++ from (e.g. learncpp.com).

Because of the mistake pointed out by Ninja.

The leak happens AFTER the last call of printf()  (main() returns, without doing delete t).   The printf() call doesn't affect that - except for the fact it is the last statement in main().

It's not the line printf("%p\n", &myStructure->param2); that causes the leak, but the fact that you are allocating the memory with malloc without later calling free, and that you allocate memory with new without later calling delete. But this are not the only issues with your code.
In C++ there is rarely any need to call operator new directly, and you almost never need to allocate memory with malloc (which doesn't call constructors).
sizeof(pMY_STRUCTURE) also certainly doesn't do what you think. It returns the size of the pointer, not of your structure, so consequently you are allocating 8 bytes (simplifying pointer size for typical x64 architecture) and then asking it to be reinterpreted as pointer to structure that should take at least 24 bytes. Accessing param3 - param6 members values would be Undefined Behavior.
